# Accessing an old 1883 paper by Kronecker?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, mathematical-german

I'm trying to find the paper by Leopold Kronecker from 1883 named "Ueber die Bernoullischen Zahlen", lots of websites have some sort of signups/paywalls to access this. Is there some online repository to look this paper up?

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-41193-3)?

Comment: @Wolgwang it has a similar name, i will try to look if it has the same equation but this is written by Louis Saalschütz. The paper is by Kronecker is small and printed in an 1883 journal "Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik"

Comment: @TeM the 2nd link is very good, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete works of Kronecker is available on the internet archive 100% free and legal(if you care about that).

https://archive.org/search.php?query=leopold%20kronecker%20werke

Comment: It's actually quite hard to locate that paper. It's [this one](https://archive.org/details/werkehrsgaufvera02kronuoft/page/402/mode/2up) on page 402.